# Return Output from SQL Function using command line SQLCMD

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Function that returns an Integer as the Output. I need to execute it via sqlcmd and I only want to get it's integer output.

However right now  I'm getting back this type of output:

```
------------
         25

<1 rows affected>
```

How can I just get back the 25?

Here's the Call I'm using:

```
 sqlcmd -S MyServer\Instance -d SQLAdmin -Q "SELECT dbo.UDF_INT_Get_Status ('INT_02')" -I
```

Comment: Good question.  This may be more suited for Database Administrators. (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `-h` flag will remove the header when passed -1 as a parameter, and the `-W` flag will remove the spaces.

Try:

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer\Instance -d SQLAdmin -Q "SELECT dbo.UDF_INT_Get_Status ('INT_02')" -h -1 -W
```